# Meta-programming with robert.hooke (building #'some.qualified/name in code)

Tags: clojure

`robert.hooke` adds hooks around methods as follows:

```
(add-hook #'fully.qualified/name-to-override
          (fn [f & args] 42)) ; override with lambda to return 42
```

I want to iterate over a vector of Symbols in order to add hooks to a number of functions, like so:

```
(doseq [f '[func-a func-b func-c]]
  (add-hook (symbol "fully.qualified" (str f))
            (fn [& args] 42)))
```

However, this doesn't work, because the symbol generated by `(symbol s1 s2)` isn't actually the function object itself. What's the correct way to do this? I've tried passing the `(symbol ...)` to `resolve-ns` too, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ns-resolve](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns-resolve) on the symbol.

```
  (ns-resolve 'fully.qualified f)
```

Comment: Isn't `'[a b c]` logically equivalent to `['a 'b 'c]` ?

Comment: Great, using `(ns-resolve 'lib.name f)` works a treat. Now I'm just confused by `(ns-resolve *ns* 'lib.name/f)` doesn't work the same way :)

Comment: Yes it's logically equivalent, removing the annotation.  *ns* refers to the current namespace, if the function is not in *ns* will not resolve

Comment: Explored this in the REPL and it makes sense, thanks!